# How do I make a sentence vertical in the middle of a horizontal sentence?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\title{Title 1}
\maketitle

Here is a sentence. Here is another sentence
                                    that will be
                                    vertical.
                                    Nice.
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure if the formatting will show on the post exactly as how I see it (different browsers and such), but basically in this example sentence, it will be normally horizontal as usual, but in the second sentence, the words "sentence," "that will be," "vertical," and "Nice" will be aligned vertically instead of continuing horizontally as usual. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two options:

1. One can manually stack the sentence in a `\Longunderstack`; or
2. One can stick a `\parbox` to let the "vertical" sentence auto-format.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\begin{document}
Here is a sentence.  Here is another 
\Longunderstack[l]{sentence\cr that will be\cr vertical.\cr Nice.}

Next paragraph.

Here is a sentence.  Here is another 
\parbox[t]{.7in}{\raggedright sentence that will be vertical. Nice.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Here's an implementation based on `tabular`, with some trick for keeping the interline spacing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% this is just for showing the interline spacing is correct
\addtolength{\textwidth}{4cm}
\calclayout
\newcommand{\checkrule}{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\vrule height 0pt depth 0.1pt width \textwidth}%
}
%

\newenvironment{vertpar}
 {\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}}
 {\end{tabular}\par\prevdepth=\dp\strutbox}

\begin{document}

\checkrule
Here is a sentence. Here is another 
\begin{vertpar}
sentence \\
that will be \\
vertical. \\
\checkrule
Nice.
\end{vertpar}

\checkrule
\lipsum[2]

\newpage

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The `\checkrule` macro is used for showing the alignment of lines with or without the special environment.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

What about `\hangindent`?

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\def\sentences{
    \noindent Here is a sentence. 
    Here is another sentence that will be vertical. 
    Nice.}

\begin{document}
\hyphenpenalty10000  
\rightskip16em
\hangindent16.5em
\sentences

\hyphenpenalty0  
\rightskip24em
\hangindent6em
\hangafter3
\sentences\sentences\sentences
\end{document}
```